# loopback-sdk-android API causes UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION at Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, loopbackjs

I'm trying to use the [loopback-android-sdk](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android) to connect my app to an API created with [loopback.io](http://loopback.io/), but when I add the dependency to my gradle build file it causes an `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION` - `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'`

the dependency line is `compile 'com.strongloop:loopback-sdk-android:1.5.+'`

I've tried with 1.5.0, 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 but the result is the same

follows the complete stack trace

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android have a limitation of 65536 classes per dex file
and you  exeded this limitation

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

this happens becouse you add libraries up the count of this classes 
to have more classes you have to enable multidex in gradle file
build.gradle:

```
android {
....
    defaultConfig {
      ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
....
```

[Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: thanks! that was the problem, just wanted to add that it looks like it's a little bit more complicated than adding that line.

I had some problems with android-support-v7, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224899/why-am-i-still-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcom) explains some possible solutions