# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException using OpenCV4

Tags: android, opencv, exception, javacameraview

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, Android Studio 3.4.1 and OpenCV 4.1.0.
I write some code for Object Detection in Android using OpenCV 4.
I generated `CameraActiviy.java` to do all. This class extends `AppCompactActivity` from

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and implements CvCameraViewListener2.

It's one week that Im trying to figure out what is the problem.
I had try this solution [MultiDexApplicton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224899/why-am-i-still-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcom), this solution [multidex android x](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/146#issuecomment-463667556) and also Invalidate Caches/Restart and Clean Build.

This is the first part of activity:

```
package org.med.objectsdetector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.dnn.Dnn;
import org.opencv.dnn.Net;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String PERMISSION_CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
private static List<String> classNames;
private Net net;
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!hasPermission())
        requestPermission();
    mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
```

Exceptions point to

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

actity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CameraActivity">

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/CameraView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have this exceptions stack:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
    at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2561)
    at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:707)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:618)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:540)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at void org.med.objectsdetector.CameraActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (CameraActivity.java:41)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7183)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med.objectsdetector-AJQ55ulE9HajBBVOKEDc1A==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/org.med
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2561)
    at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:707)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:618)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:540)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at void org.med.objectsdetector.CameraActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (CameraActivity.java:41)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7183)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I can't extend MultiDexApplication because I would lose all my overrided functions.

EDIT 0

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.med.objectsdetector"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':OpenCV')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

I forget permissions request part in 'CameraAtivity.java'.I have update code above.

Comment: Can you show what your build.gradle (app) file has?

Comment: @Eenvincible editetd...I also forgot Camera Permission. Thanks :)

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` change to androidx also and try

Comment: I replace with `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` but now it's a warning. No problem! Thanks! it works!